# Close react component on click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having this cookies component and it has button "I agree". I want to close this component when I click button but I have issue with making it work. I know that onClick on button should trigger something that will do it but I'm not sure where to go from that place. Thank you for advice!

```
import React from "react";
import { Content, ContentContainer, CookiesWrapper, Title } from "./styles";

export function Cookies() {
  return (
    <CookiesWrapper>
      <ContentContainer>
        <Title>
          <span>We use cookies</span>
        </Title>
        <Content>
          <span>Read more on our Privacy Policy.</span>
          <HoverableDefaultRoundBorderButton
            onClick={/*close component */}
            text="I agree"
          />
        </Content>
      </ContentContainer>
    </CookiesWrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: you can use it like a modal call, the handleOpen shoud be placet on the button outside componente, inside the componente you need to have the state of handleOpen, then inside componente you  handleClose setting the state to off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a state to control this:

```
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  if(!isOpen){
    return null
  }

  return (
    <CookiesWrapper> ... </CookiesWrapper>
  )
```

And update `onClick`:

```
  onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
```

Comment: @kate if it was helpful please don't forget to accept an answer and if you think it deserves an upvote - upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import { Content, ContentContainer, CookiesWrapper, Title } from "./styles";

export function Cookies() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(true);
  return isOpen ? (
    <CookiesWrapper>
      <ContentContainer>
        <Title>
          <span>We use cookies</span>
        </Title>
        <Content>
          <span>We use cookies and other tracking technologies to improve your browsing experience on our website, to analyze our website traffic, and to understand where our visitors are coming from. By browsing our website, you consent to our use of cookies and other tracking technologies. Read more on our Privacy Policy.</span>
          <HoverableDefaultRoundBorderButton
            onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
            text="I agree"
          />
        </Content>
      </ContentContainer>
    </CookiesWrapper>
  ):null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can use state and return the component or empty render

According to your code it may looks like

```
import React from "react";
import { Content, ContentContainer, CookiesWrapper, Title } from "./styles";

export function Cookies() {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = React.useState(true);
  if (!showPopup) return null;

  return (
    <CookiesWrapper>
      <ContentContainer>
        <Title>
          <span>We use cookies</span>
        </Title>
        <Content>
          <span>We use cookies and other tracking technologies to improve your browsing experience on our website, to analyze our website traffic, and to understand where our visitors are coming from. By browsing our website, you consent to our use of cookies and other tracking technologies. Read more on our Privacy Policy.</span>
          <HoverableDefaultRoundBorderButton
            onClick={() => setShowPopup(false)}
            text="I agree"
          />
        </Content>
      </ContentContainer>
    </CookiesWrapper>
  );
}
```